# SQL grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, grouping

I have a table with the following columns:

```
A   B   C
---------
1   10  X
1   11  X
2   15  X
3   20  Y
4   15  Y
4   20  Y
```

I want to group the data based on the B and C columns and count the distinct values of the A column. But if there are two ore more rows where the value on the A column is the same I want to get the maximum value from the B column.

If I do a simple group by the result would be:

```
B   C    Count
--------------
10  X    1
11  X    1
15  X    1
20  Y    2
15  Y    1
```

What I want is this result:

```
B   C    Count
--------------
11  X    1
15  X    1
20  Y    2
```

Is there any query that can return this result. Server is SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Does the A and C column always go together? Meaning, could you have a 5-15-X and 5-17-Y ? (varying X/Y between the two)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to work in steps: first get rid of duplicate A records, then group. Not the most efficient, but it works on your example.

```
with t1 as (
    select A, max(B) as B, C 
        from YourTable
        group by A, C
)
select count(A) as CountA, B, C
    from t1
    group by B, C
```

Comment: yes, that works :)
Was trying to hard to use a single query...and forgot other alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

I have actually tested this:

```
SELECT 
    MAX( B ) AS B,
    C,
    Count 
FROM
(
    SELECT
        B, C, COUNT(DISTINCT A) AS Count
    FROM
        t
    GROUP BY
    B, C
) X
GROUP BY C, Count
```

and it gives me:

```
 B     C     Count    
 ----  ----  -------- 
 15    X     1        
 15    y     1        
 20    y     2
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. This should work in Oracle, although I haven't tested it;

```
select count(a), BB, CC from
(
select a, max(B) BB, Max(C) CC
from yourtable
group by a
)
group by BB,CC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cteA AS 
(
    SELECT 
        A, C, 
        MAX(B) OVER(PARTITION BY A, C) [Max]
    FROM T1
)

SELECT 
    [Max] AS B, C, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT A) AS [Count]
FROM cteA
GROUP BY C, [Max];
```